# Is it possible to get comments from facebook on a topic through graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i want to get comments and sub comments from facebook is it possible through their api or are there any alternatives from where i can do it . 
I want the comment , date and if possible location of the user

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a user's location, but you can get the comment and date/time.

Docs can be found here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/comment

Access would either require manage_pages and a page token valid for the respective page or Page Public Content Access feature approved.